# How to assign a dynamic prop to v2table - Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How to assign a dynamic prop to v2table - Vue?

I cannot assign value in prop property.

Could anyone help?

Thank you very much

```
<v2-table-column  label="Vencimento" sortable align="center" width="110" prop="row.expiration_date|formatDate">
                        <template slot-scope="row">
                            <span class="sel-string">{{ row.expiration_date|formatDate }}</span>
                        </template>
                    </v2-table-column>
```

Comment: Try with giving colon ( : ) infront of prop="row.expiration_date|formatDate" e.g :prop="row.expiration_date|formatDate"

Comment: row does not work because it is out of scope of the template. Already tried.

Comment: is your field name (which is prop) this {{row.expiration_date|formatDate}}, If so then exactly you can't access row outside. I will suggest to create a separate array with field name.